# Re-direct if query doesn't match current date

Tags: mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I run an image based site, I'm having problems with downloading plugin Image Host Grabber, as well as direct linking to files and not web pages on twitter/facebook etc (as there is a referrer, common hot linking protection doesn't work).

I have a solution (seen on other websites), which is to use a query string on the media file.jpg**?1234545**

I have mod_rewrite set up to redirect to a useless meme if their is no ?query at all with:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://www.my-site.com/grrrr.jpg
```

I also want to redirect to my grrrr.jpg if the query doesn't match today's date in number format, for example today 16th March 2013 to ?1632013

**This is all i have so far, which doesn't work**

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}  ^%{TIME_DAY}%{TIME_MON}%{TIME_YEAR}
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://www.my-site.com/grrrr.jpg
```

I can't even get it to react to the current year ?2013 with just ${TIME_YEAR}

Can anyone tell me where i'm going wrong, I'm moderately advanced with PHP, but useless with mod_rewrite

Thanks in advance